# Security input on Next.js app with Prisma/Postgresql (SQL injections etc.)

Tags: postgresql, next.js, jwt, prisma

I made my first Next.js app, with Prisma handling data in Postgresql. I use jsonwebtoken for authentication and all the tech is new to me, I come from old school classic asp, serverside sessions and direct MySQL queries :-)

Am I correct in assuming that I do not need to worry about SQL injections with Prisma? I am not using queryRaw/executeRaw etc., only standard find/update/create/delete.

Apart from that, does anyone have any recommendations for tools/services that I should run to look for common flaws? or like a checklist of beginner mistakes?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using some reputable library for authentication rather than implementing everything from scratch. While OSS libraries may not be 100% bullet proof, they already implement numerous best-practices that are easy to overlook when implementing on your own. You can find a list of recommended libraries and providers in Next.js docs - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/authenticating